# Converting curl to ansible uri POST request

Tags: curl, uri, influxdb

I have the following curl command:

```
curl -i -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=somedb" --data-binary "total,type=stats value=25 $epoch"
```

I can add data to this database using this command easily. However, I'd like a URI equivalent to this command, which I can't seem to find online. I know a get request looks like this:

```
http://example:8086/query?q=show%20databases
```

How would I do my POST request with the data that I currently have?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the detail answer from Ansible `uri` module, here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html

Example for your particular question:

```
- uri:
    url: http://localhost:8086/write?db=somedb
    method: POST
    body_format: raw
    body: "total,type=stats value=25 $epoch"
    status_code: 200
```

Comment: How would I put the body data in a URL though?